# Koa.js, Mongo DB application not returning any results using Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose, koa

I am having a problem whereas I cannot get any results returned from a collection within a MongoDB. The db exists as does the collection and querying the MongoDB collection from the Mongo CLI returns results. i always get empty results back from the find() query within my application codebase.

My application is transpiled at runtime using babel-register.

My app.js file:

```
import Koa from 'koa';
import path from 'path';
import bodyParser from 'koa-bodyparser';
import serve from 'koa-static';
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import Config from '../Config.js';

global.appRoot = path.resolve(__dirname);

const app = new Koa();

mongoose.connect(Config.mongo.url);
mongoose.connection.on('connected', (response) => {
    console.log(response);
});
mongoose.connection.on('error', (err) => {
    console.log(err);
});
............
```

This works fine and the on('connected'... callback works fine and is called.

My users schema:

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const UserSchema = new Schema({
    username: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true,
        lowercase: true
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required:
        true
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true
    }
});

export default mongoose.model('user', UserSchema);
```

My routes file:

```
import Router from 'koa-router';
import authenticate from '../../middlewares/authenticate';
import mockCustomerService from '../../mock-services/customerService';
import AccountController from '../../controllers/accountController';
import UserModel from '../../models/UserModel';

const AccountControllerInstance = new AccountController(UserModel);

const authRouter = new Router();


/** Login function **/
authRouter.post('/login', async (ctx, next) => {
     AccountControllerObject.login(ctx)
    .then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
    });
});
```

As you can see I inject the user schema into the AccountControllerInstance

Account Controller class

```
import ApiResponse from '../models/ApiResponse.js';
import ApiMessages from '../models/ApiMessages.js';
import UserProfileModel from '../models/UserProfileModel.js';

class AccountController {
    constructor(userModel, token) {
        this.ApiResponse = ApiResponse;
        this.ApiMessages = ApiMessages;
        this.UserProfileModel = UserProfileModel;
        this.userModel = userModel;
        this.token = token;
    }


    login(ctx) {

        return this.userModel.find({ email: ctx.request.body.email });

    }
```

This controller contains the functions to login, register etc. As you can see, the user schema is put as a property of the class in the constructor.
I then use the login function to query the Mongo instance but I never get any results returned. I have checked there are correct records in the collection and made sure the query (email in this case) is exact but still no results.

Here is an example of a record in the 'users' collection on the 'degould-login' database generated by the mongo cli with a find query.

```
db.user.find({email: "james.alex.holman@gmail.com"})
```

Result:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("594a313a98e5b9f2f9dc9553"), "email" : "james.alex.holman@gmail.com", "username" : "james", "password" : "test" }
```

Anyone see what's happening here?

Thanks

Comment: Why are you wrapping with Promises? The mongoose methods already return Promises. You can call `.exec()` to get a "full" Promise, but they all have a `.then()` by default anyway. I think you might find things work if you just return the response from the plain methods.

Comment: Sorry that was a mistake. I have amended the functions and the Mongo db is still not returning any results.

Comment: Show your edited code please. I still see a `reject` in there so I'm not sure if you edited the question or pasted your real code in. And check your inputs to make sure you are putting in what you think you are putting in.

Comment: Apologies was a copy-paste error. I have amended the code to what you suggest and still have no results in the response. I can see the correction collection and database are selected and the email search term - 'james.alex.holman@gmail.com'. It's really bizarre

Answer (score 0):

In app.js first you will connected with mongo via mongoose then you will load all file.
In this you are not loading router and model.
And you know mongoose connection is asynchronous, so you write code in sync way for loading models and routers. For this you will use async -await pattern or callback.